# Выпилить [ремонт]!

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, удаление-метки

Предлагаю выпилить метку [ремонт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82) и те 3 вопроса, что ей отмечены, т.к. они оффтопик (не соответствуют теме сайта).

Собственно суть - прошу согласия модераторского состава и бана метки.

Comment: состав не против

Comment: Кстати, недостаточно каламбуров в вопросе о метках. [Нужно больше каламбуров!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295583/2790048)

Comment: А еще есть `фигура` http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: @Visman ох ты ё ..

Comment: @Visman: там не хватает метки [tag:как-на-картинке]

Comment: `background` http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/background несет ли какой-то смысл?

Comment: @Visman попробуйте спросить в чате или создайте новую тему. Тут все про "ремонт" ;-)

Comment: Лентяй я. Вот еще http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javaskript

Comment: @Visman почти никакого. Я бы удалил.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, удалил метку из всех вопросов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выпилил, ещё и по [железо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be) прошелся немного.

Думаю, нам стоит обсудить вопросы по железу в свете тематики сайта. И либо все позакрывать (что не означает удаления), либо расширить тематику.

Comment: Имхо "железо" слишком обширная тема, чтобы ее можно было поместить в одни рамки с программированием.

Comment: @KromStern: задал отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Предлагаю `железо` переделать в `оргтехника`.

Comment: @dsnk, за что ж его так?

Comment: @Qwertiy там по большей части вопросы по оргтехнике, а вопросов по схемотехнике мне тут не попадалось.

Comment: @dsnk, зато к тематике ближе. Кстати, на железо тут где-то рядом тема была.